# How to not use MAX when using CASE

Tags: mysql

Is there any way I can use CASE but not use MAX in getting the value that I want?
My current query is like this

```
SELECT
    ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN id = '1' THEN value END),2) Val1,   
    ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN id = '2' THEN value END),2) Val2,
    ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN id = '3' THEN value END),2) Val3

FROM table
WHERE id IN ("1", "2", "3") and

t_stamp BETWEEN "2014-10-25" AND "2014-10-25"

GROUP BY DATE(t_stamp), HOUR(t_stamp), MINUTE(t_stamp)  DIV 15
```

It would be great if i can just get the actual value for those times and not the MAX value.

I tried removing the MAX but all the output became NULL

```
SELECT
    ROUND((CASE WHEN id = '1' THEN value END),2) Val1,  
    ROUND((CASE WHEN id = '2' THEN value END),2) Val2,
    ROUND((CASE WHEN id = '3' THEN value END),2) Val3

FROM table
WHERE id IN ("1", "2", "3") and

t_stamp BETWEEN "2014-10-25" AND "2014-10-25"

GROUP BY DATE(t_stamp), HOUR(t_stamp), MINUTE(t_stamp)  DIV 15
```

How can I do this? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that really MySQL is letting you do something that it shouldn't do.

In standard SQL, if you have a GROUP BY clause, every element in you SELECT clause has to fit into one of two categories:

1)  Its an aggregate function MAX, SUM, COUNT, etc.
2)  It is ALSO named in the GROUP BY clause.

The issue you are seeing is that when you don't have a "MAX", MySQL chooses a value from an arbitrary row.

Read more about this (terrible) behavior here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

I've created this SQLFiddle for you:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c17f6/4

What behavior are you looking for when there are multiple "values" in the same 15 minute time range for the same id?  My guess is that you want MAX, AVG, SUM, or FIRST

Comment: I definitely don't want to use MAX, i think FIRST would be the next choice. How do I do that? Just change MAX to FIRST?

Comment: Well, I knew you'd say that since MySQL doesn't implement FIRST.  It might help if you explained what this data actually means.  Maybe you could use GROUP_CONCAT to better understand your data?

Comment: yes i checked group_concat and i think i will just use that. But.. how do i use it to the query that i already have? can i just change MAX to GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: i didn't even know about GROUP_CONCAT (I still have a lot to learn when using mysql) this will be handy in the future. Thanks a lot!

Comment: oh crap wait, how come its not following the time interval? i need it to be in 15 mins interval like 12:00, 12:15, 12:30... but now its not getting the value for those times

Comment: My guess is that it IS following the time interval.... you just need to interpret date/hour/minute columns to determine which one it is?